# JSON to array - How to parse for such a structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My JSON object has the following structure :

```
{ key :
[
{keya1:value1,
keya2:value2,
keya3:[value31,value32...]
keya4:value4
},
{keyb1:value1,
keyb2:value2,
keyb3:[value31,value32...]
keyb4:value4
},
...
..
{keys1:value1,
keys2:value2,
keys3:[value31,value32...]
keys4:value4
}
]
}
```

I tried using a simple json.parse but it doesnt work.
With such a structure how should i go about parsing so that i can safely iterate over each instances of key and display all keya-valuea,keyb-valueb.. pairs for values of key?
Many thanks!

EDIT : I actually omitted quotes on purpose. The original JSON data HAS quotes around keys and values.Sorry i didnt mention it earlier.

Comment: Your actually better off getting this data structure to be properly json formatted. It will make it much easier on your part! Can you explain how the data is being generated?

Comment: Your json is invalid: Key names have to be quoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using getJsonArray

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(response);

JSONArray array= json.getJSONArray("key");
```

or `getString("key");` where applicable

Comment: I'm afraid this wouldn't work because the data is not formatted like JSON. Mainly the issue is that there is no double quotes around any of the strings.

Comment: Pretty sure the OP is using javascript

Comment: Also the OP asked for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid, you need the double quotes and comma after your array, when you have a correct JSON you could use `JSON.parse`

```
{ "key" :
        [{
          "keya1":"value1",
          "keya2":"value2",
          "keya3":["value31","value32..."],
          "keya4":"value4"
         },
         {
          "keyb1":"value1",
          "keyb2":"value2",
          "keyb3":["value31","value32..."],
          "keyb4":"value4"
         },
         {
          "keys1":"value1",
          "keys2":"value2",
          "keys3":["value31","value32..."],
          "keys4":"value4"
         }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to quote each key and value:

```
var str = '{ key : \
    [ \
        {\
            keya1:value1, \
            keya2:value2, \
            keya3:[value31,value32], \
            keya4:value4 \
        }, \
        {\
            keyb1:value1, \
            keyb2:value2, \
            keyb3:[value31,value32], \
            keyb4:value4 \
        }, \
        {\
            keys1:value1, \
            keys2:value2, \
            keys3:[value31,value32], \
            keys4:value4 \
        } \
    ] \
}';

var pattern=/(\w+\d*)/ig;
var json=str.replace(pattern, '"$1"');
var parsedJSON=JSON.parse(json)
console.log(parsedJSON);
```

I hope this helps.